# How to show a soft-keyboard when EditText is selected?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I tried using the accepted answer here but this does not work for me!

[android - show soft keyboard on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475135/android-show-soft-keyboard-on-demand)

Any advice is appreciated :)

Comment: Post your code. Everything I have read says that your link should work.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, my editText is part of a titleLayout that I am including in this activity. i.e in the first (landing)activity of the main-tabbed-activity, the softkeyboard shows up when the editText is selected. But if I go to the second activity in the main-tabbed-activity w/o using the softkeyboard in the first instance, the softkeyboard does not show up!

Comment: In what way is it not working? Can you provide a bit more detail to your question - i.e. the code you are using and the actual outcome?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

I finally go it to work. All I had to do was to clear the focus when I navigate from one activity to another. :)

Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code (which seems so obvious now) did the trick:

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
 activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```