# Know default keyboard on android

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I want to know the default keyboard chosen by the user in Android. I know  I can access the list of enabled input methods using the `InputMethodManager`, but I want to know which one is the user currently using.

So far, I've tried to get the current input method subtype:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype subtype =imeManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
```

But this object only seems to give me the Locale the user has picked and the input type (voice, keyboard,..).

I've also tried through the list of enabled input methods:

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
List<InputMethodInfo> list =imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    for(InputMethodInfo i: list){
        ...
    }
```

However the class `InputMethodInfo` does not contain information of whether this method is the default input method or not.

I know there must be a way, because everytime I open SwiftKey Keyboard and is not set as the default keyboard a input method picker appears. So, how do they know their keyboard is not currently set as default?

I'm aware this question might be a duplicate, since it's the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678258/how-programmatically-switch-to-default-softkeyboard) one. However that question didn't get an answer, so I'm really hoping someone can help me now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this to get default keyboard.

```
Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

To get more information about current keyboard:

```
for(InputMethodInfo i: list){
  if (i.getId().equals(Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {
    ...
  }
}
```