# Prevent the use of Custom Keyboard

Tags: android, android-security, keylogger

## Description

I want to detect whether the user is using the default keyboard or a custom keyboard. I've found this code on how to get the default keyboard, and the list of keyboards: [Know default keyboard on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803878/know-default-keyboard-on-android).

The problem is, there's no good way to detect if the keyboard chosen was the system default or not.

## Why

We're doing this as a security to prevent key logging. Is there any better approach to detect and prevent key logging?

Comment: If all else fails, you can create your own keyboard out of buttons and disable system/custom keyboards all together.

Comment: Hm, I guess this should be our last resort as this might take a lot of time. Ill take this into consideration. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no direct way in doing this. The easiest one (not that easy actually) is by **collecting all of the list of default keyboard in each model/brand of phones, and validate** within it. This was also the solution of one of the private security SDK that I've known.

The other solution (thanks to @Garren Fitzenreiter) is by **creating a custom keyboard** in the app and use that instead.

And lastly, the easiest one (this is really easy, because this is not an actual solution haha) is just by **putting it inside your app's terms and conditions** indicating that the user should avoid any custom keyboards.