# How can I set the focus (and display the keyboard) on my EditText programmatically

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a layout which contains some views like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView...>
<TextView...>
<ImageView ...>
<EditText...>
<Button...>
</linearLayout>
```

How can I set the focus (display the keyboard) on my `EditText` programmatically?

I've tried this and it works only when I launch my `Activity` normally, but when I launch it in a `TabHost`, it doesn't work.

```
txtSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
txtSearch.setFocusable(true);
txtSearch.requestFocus();
```

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/93/android-show-hide-soft-keyboard-programmatically/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused)

Answer (score 436, accepted):

Try this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

Comment: Updated with code to force the keyboard to show from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused

Comment: it works only when i launch my activity normally , but when i launch my activity on a TabHost , it doesn't work ,

Comment: How are you setting up your TabHost?

Comment: @Sharmilee : yes, i've changed the TabActivity to FragmentActivity and it works using the code above. To show or hide keyboard programmatically , you can see this tutorial :http://bit.ly/1kCmP9s

Comment: This doesnt work. This one works for me InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

Comment: "This doesn't work brother". In some cases you need to call this code asynchronously from postDelayed(). I had a case when I had to open keyboard after user pressed "OK" on the dialog. And when dialog was closing it was messing with the focus. So I've called the code above from postDelayed(). It executed after dialog had closed. Profit.

Comment: but this method open up keyboard forcefully, and even when we close app via home button, keyboard will be there.

Comment: 237 up votes on the answer and 62 on "it doesn't work brother" I tested it to get own opinion and it works perfect!)

Comment: What is **Context**?

Comment: I don't know why "This doesn't work brother" get so many upvote.. But it works for me

Comment: @Minkoo, no, this method works well with Home button. But `InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED` solution really has a bug with Home button.

Comment: @zihadrizkyef, this method sometimes doesn't work. In TabHost, AlertDialog and in onCreateView. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663774/2914140.

Comment: Just to share the experience: I just added the code to four different fragments within my current app project. With the first three fragments the code worked flawlessly. With the last fragment no keyboard was shown until I started the code from onViewCreated with a 100ms delay using Kotlin Coroutines.

Comment: Addendum: I found another fragment where I needed the 100ms delay plus a view.clearFocus() before executing the code.

Comment: This is not a general solution since it DOES NOT work for FRAGMENTS!!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, maybe not IN a fragment, but called FROM a fragment. The EditText was in a fragment that contained a pageview collection, so it wasn't exactly a simple process, but still worked fine.

Answer (score 183):

use:

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: After trying more than 5 other approaches, this was the only one that worked for me (from a `View` subclass)

Comment: This suggestion lead to the keyboard being fixed, even when the field looses focus.

Comment: yes, it works for me too, and `imm.showSoftInput()` doesn't work.

Comment: While this method does work, it has a down side, quitting the application with the home button (hardware) will let the keyboard on screen. You will have to press the return button (hardware) to hide the keyboard despise it being useless on your home screen.

Comment: Other approaches didn't work for me, this one did. thank you.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies You're right. A possible solution, would be override onPause or onStop and then hide the keyboard.

Comment: This worked for me also when showing keyboard on dialog open.

Comment: this solution clear all the existing text on edittext. Any body faced such issue ??

Comment: This makes me have to double tap to show it. The accepted answer doesn't need to.

Answer (score 61):

This worked for me, 
Thanks to [ungalcrys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28596779/3896354)

Show keyboard:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Hide keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: The only full solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 57):

```
final EditText tb = new EditText(this);
tb.requestFocus();
tb.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(tb, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I had to do this in order to get it showing up in onResume().   Without the delay, nothing would happen using every single solution described in this thread.

Comment: There it is. That was the answer I was looking for. Though, you don't necesarily need an entire second delay. I tried just 150 millis, and that worked fine as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works even for 0 ms (`tb.post({ showKeyboard(tb) })`). Notice that we need a EditText view (`tb`), not a fragment view.

Answer (score 44):

`showSoftInput` was not working for me at all.

I figured I needed to set the input mode : `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` (here in the Activity component in the manifest)

Hope this help!

Comment: This just showed the keyboard when the activity was started.

Comment: Awesome :) Tried a bunch of answers but only with this, I could make it work :) Thank you so much.

Comment: very underrated answer

Comment: Perfect answer. Works with only "editText.requestFocus()". Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Here is how a kotlin extension for showing and hiding the soft keyboard can be made:

```
fun View.showKeyboard() {
  this.requestFocus()
  val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
  val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
editText.showKeyboard()
// OR
editText.hideKeyboard()
```

Comment: this is a better solution as compared to rest

Comment: This worked for me in mar 2021. Did it in a Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed( { ... }, 1000)

Comment: This works great. Additionally, if the Fragment is dismissed containing the View which showKeyboard() was called on, the keyboard is automatically dismissed. I had trouble using imm where the keyboard was not dismissed when I dismissed the Fragment.

Comment: Very elegant. The superiority of this solution is evident.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using a [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) which is part of the [Handling Lifecycles with Lifecycle-Aware Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) of [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack).

I want to open and close the Keyboard when the Fragment/Activity appears. Firstly, define two [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for the EditText. You can put them anywhere in your project:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    requestFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}

fun EditText.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
}
```

Then define a LifecycleObserver which opens and closes the keyboard when the Activity/Fragment reaches `onResume()` or `onPause`:

```
class EditTextKeyboardLifecycleObserver(private val editText: WeakReference<EditText>) :
    LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun openKeyboard() {
        editText.get()?.postDelayed({ editText.get()?.showKeyboard() }, 100)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun closeKeyboard() {
        editText.get()?.hideKeyboard()
    }
}
```

Then add the following line to any of your Fragments/Activities, you can reuse the LifecycleObserver any times. E.g. for a Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // inflate the Fragment layout

    lifecycle.addObserver(EditTextKeyboardLifecycleObserver(WeakReference(myEditText)))

    // do other stuff and return the view

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is KeyboardHelper Class for hiding and showing keyboard

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by khanhamza on 06-Mar-17.
 */

public class KeyboardHelper {
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(final Context context, final View view) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    view.requestFocus();
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
assert imm != null;
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
}, 1000);
}

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(final Context context, final EditText editText) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
assert imm != null;
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
}, 1000);
}


public static void openSoftKeyboard(final Context context, final EditText editText) {
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
assert imm != null;
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
}, 1000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put this into onResume() method.

```
binding.etxtSearch.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
binding.etxtSearch.isFocusable = true
binding.etxtSearch.requestFocus() 
val inputMethodManager = context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(binding.etxtSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot ways and it's not working tho, not sure is it because i'm using shared transition from fragment to activity containing the edit text.

Btw my edittext is also wrapped in LinearLayout.

I added a slight delay to request focus and below code worked for me: 
(Kotlin)

```
 et_search.postDelayed({
     editText.requestFocus()

     showKeyboard()
 },400) //only 400 is working fine, even 300 / 350, the cursor is not showing
```

showKeyboard()

```
 val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
 imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
editTxt.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            if (hasFocus) {
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
            } else {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the top answer by David Merriman and it also didn't work in my case. But I found the suggestion to run this code delayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520085/android-show-softkeyboard-with-showsoftinput-is-not-working) and it works like a charm.

```
val editText = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.settings_input_text)

editText.postDelayed({
    editText.requestFocus()

    val imm = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    imm?.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late reply, but for people who are like me looking to do this in 2022, to find out that toggleSoftInput is deprecated (as of level 31), here is the new approach using showSoftInput:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
editView.requestFocus();
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                        .showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I tried the toggleSoftInput but found some issues, like the keyboard stays when I press the home button,but this approach worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Using this code for show keyboard programmatically.

```
binding!!.etAssignToName.postDelayed( {
                mActivity.runOnUiThread {
                    showKeyboard(binding!!.etAssignToName,mContext)
                }
            },300)

fun showKeyboard(editText: EditText, context: Context) {
editText.requestFocus()
val imm: InputMethodManager =
    context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0)}

fun View.hideSoftKeyboard(context: Context) {
val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)}
```

Answer (score 2):

**kotlin:**

```
fun View.showKeyboard() {
  this.requestFocus()
  val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
  val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

**use:**

```
yourEditText.post{
    yourEditText.showKeyboard()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like others, I had to add a delay to show the keyboard, but `after` setting the focus. YMMV

```
private fun View.showKeyboard() {
    this.requestFocus()
    this.postDelayed({
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }, 100)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First way**:

```
    etPassword.post(() -> {
        etPassword.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        manager.showSoftInput(etPassword, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    });
```

**Second way**:

In Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"/>
```

In code:

```
etPassword.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a solution and create a Kotlin class for it

```kotlin
object KeyboardUtils {

    fun showKeyboard(editText: EditText) {
        editText.requestFocus()
        val imm = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0)
    }

    fun hideKeyboard(editText: EditText) {
        val imm = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.windowToken, 0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In "OnCreate" move the cursor to the input field, but the keyboard will not open:

```
window().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN
)
editText.requestFocus()
```

After that, while the user enters the text:

```
val imm = editText.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
window.setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE
)
imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0)
```

will work adequately and the keyboard will open when needed without setting time delays.
Remember, after entering the text, you must:

```
window.setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN
)
requestFocus()
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it only in one line of code

```
firstInputField.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.id_of_next_targeted_text_field);
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get any of these answers to work on their own. The solution for me was to combine them:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
editText.requestFocus();
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

I'm not sure why that was required for me -- according to the docs it seems that either method should have worked on their own.

Comment: This is definitely not a good practice. Perhaps, Activity or Fragment transaction was intervening with the soft keyboard or the Input Method flags were not set correctly but either way, this solution should not be used.