# Android: force keyboard to appear and focus on EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

Thanks in advance for the help.

I would like a keyboard to appear at the end or during the execution of the following code.

```
    // edit text
    EditText editText = new EditText(activity);
    editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    editText.setText("Type here...");

    RelativeLayout relativeLayoutEditText = new RelativeLayout(activity);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramRelativeLayoutEditText = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 43 * display.getHeight() / 80 );
    paramRelativeLayoutEditText.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    relativeLayoutEditText.addView(editText,paramRelativeLayoutEditText);

    // add all created views to rootView
    rootView.addView(relativeLayoutEditText, paramEditText);

    // open keyboard
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

but the keyboard only appears after touching the editText field (ie with my finger).  Is there a way that I can make the board automatically appear without using a physical touch?

As an aside I know that how I am specifying the width and height isn't exactly the right way to do things.

Comment: editText.requestFocus();  can you add this code after setTextMethod()?

Comment: I've tried that already.  editText gets focus but the keyboard still doesn't appear until I touch the screen.

Comment: Possible answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8991563/3913366

Comment: That did it @Shubham!.  It wasn't the accepted answer though.  It was the second answer down (ie imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); ).  If you write up an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to @Shubham's link I was able to figure it out.  The solution was not the answer given in the link, however.  It was the second answer.

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Edit:

once using the above solution the keyboard will remain on the screen until a user presses either the back button or the home button (sometimes it takes a few times).  To remove the keyboard use this

```
imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0,0);
```

in my case rootView is the rootView of the current activity.  I have not tested this to see if this will work on child views.

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
    editText.requestFocus();
```

Try this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

ensure that the edittext is focusable in touch mode. You can do it two way.

In xml:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

in Java:

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Same thing.  editText gets focus but the the keyboard doesn't appear until I touch the screen.

Comment: The problem isn't really getting it to focus.  editText.requestFocus(); seems to work doing that by itself, but the keyboard is staying hidden until I physically touch the screen.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" add in activity manifest

Comment: I tried that previously but I can't have the keyboard always visible (I'm not really using xml since my code is fairly dynamic).  I would assume that it is possible to do the same with code which is what I've been looking at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87963/discussion-between-sasikumar-and-user2736423).

Comment: I just found a solution thanks to @Shubham.  See his link and the second answer down.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
EditText textView = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
textView.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()

Answer (score 0):

Possible [answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8991563/3913366). Many of the above are also sourced from this link.

Try This :

```
EditText textView = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
textView.requestFocus();    
InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: give the actual solution.

Comment: That's not the solution.......  Second answer was it.  See my comment previously.

Answer (score 0):

this will show the keypad

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        OrderMainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(txtCustomerId, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

enter your activity name instead of this if you calling keypad from the listeners eg. button click