# Android - show keyboard programmatically

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an `EditText` field which is disabled at the beginning.

I would like to set it to enabled, put the cursor on it and the keyboard should be visible.

I tried the following code and all works - only the keyboard will not be shown.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState{
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991522/how-can-i-set-the-focus-and-display-the-keyboard-on-my-edittext-programmatic

Comment: this is the same code as my code

Comment: there are other upvoted answers.Have you tried them??

Answer (score 123, accepted):

> This is possibly a deprecated solution now.

For hiding keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

For Showing keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)   getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: I run your code in `onCreate` and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Since you're using "toggleSoftInput" to show keyboard you can use it for both showing and hiding since its toggling.

Comment: toggleSoftInput is deprecated

Comment: Use imm.showSoftInput(view, 0) instead of toggleSoftInput as it's depreciated.

Answer (score 17):

try my showKeyboard method

```
 public static void showKeyboard(EditText mEtSearch, Context context) {
    mEtSearch.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
}

public static void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText mEtSearch, Context context) {
    mEtSearch.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEtSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);


}
```

Comment: I'd just remove Context from params and take it from mEtSearch.getContext()

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method for showing keyboard forcefully after calling `requestFocus()` on EditText.

```
public static void showKeyboard(FragmentActivity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }
```