# How to set focus on editText Preference and show keyboard automatically?

Tags: java, android, preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencescreen

I am learning the Preferences and I have created this

[image]

**After clicking on EditText I am getting this**

[image]

**What I am trying to do is this.**

[image]

**The keybord and focus on edittext only shows when I click on it. I want it automatically when I click on EditText(This is editxText).**

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991522/how-can-i-set-the-focus-and-display-the-keyboard-on-my-edittext-programmatical

Comment: On popup you need to set focus in edittext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your preference fragment that extends from `PreferenceFragmentCompat` override `onResume()` with below

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Preference search = findPreference(getString(R.string.setting_edit_text_key));
    search.performClick();
}
```

Illustration: you inflate the EditTextPreference using its key, and perform a click on it.

Comment: One thing, there is no method named as performClick().
You have to use setOnPrefernceClickListener()\

Comment: Hi @VivekVerma it seems that you are using `Preference` from `android.preference` package instead of `android.support.v7.preference package`; `performClick()` is available at the later one

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this :

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    editText.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: It is an EditText Preference, not an edit text, I can not access it by its id bcz it does not have an id, it has a key