# Input Text into Invisible EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

My question is on invoking the soft-keyboard in Android.

I am trying out the FingerPaint (API Demos), which is essentially a touch-drawing app. Attempting to give it a touch text-input interface, I added EditText inside the CustomView class, like the following:

```
private void inputText() {

    EditText newText = new EditText(getContext());  
        //getContext needed as we're in a class extending View, not activity

    newText.setText("Text Text Text");

       //'addView' is deliberately left out for invisibility
       //'requestFocus' also left out

       // Show soft keyboard for the user to enter the value.
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) ConfigKey.context.getSystemService("input_method"); 
    imm.showSoftInput(newText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    String newTextString = newText.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(newTextString);
  }
```

The EditText was added alright (as seen from the Logcat, "Text Text Text") but there was just no keyboard to be seen for inputing.

Any way to fix it?

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED? Flag for showSoftInput(View, int) to indicate that this is an implicit request to show the input window, not as the result of a direct request by the user. The window may not be shown in this case.

Comment: imm.showSoftInput did not seem to work (haven't exhausted all possible params). At your hint, however, I've just tried imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0), and it worked to some point as it just showed the keyboard but did not take any input (again, as shown by Logcat). This question has been discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694995/android-softkeyboard-showsoftinput-vs-togglesoftinput, but to no avail.