# Android How to showKeyboard without delay time?

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I want to show keyboard when activity onCreate and don't delay any time.

I check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694995/android-softkeyboard-showsoftinput-vs-togglesoftinput/16639415) and found the answer. Itˊs works but I don't know why

Can anyone tell me why the code works. Thanks!!

Here is the code 
Here is the code 
Here is the code 
Here is the code 
Here is the code

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
class Test: BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        ...
    }

    private fun showKeyboard(view: View) {

        val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        view.requestFocus()
        imm.showSoftInput(view, 0)
    }
}
```

I tried some methods in onCreate

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        showKeyboard(edittext)// doesn't work
    }
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        Handler().postDelayed({

            showKeyboard(edittext)
        },500)// It works but I don't want to delay 500 mills
    }
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        edittext.post {

            showKeyboard(edittext)// doesn't work
        }
    }
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        edittext.post {

            edittext.post {

                showKeyboard(edittext)// It works but why???
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this sir

```
  val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank for comment. It works. But why the double post works?

Comment: @GuanHongHuang i dont really know but i guess when you call double post, it seem you call delay. So edittext can be requested.