# Why android InputMethodManager.showSoftInput() returns false?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

Recently while developing an app, I faced an issue. I have searched a lot on google but couldn't find any solution. In the end I came across this [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25812)

To explain my issue, I have made a sample App.

**Basic Working of my Sample App**

1. I have a screen, which has an EditText, a Button and a RelativeLayout.
2. Width and Height of RelativeLayout is 0px. It is just a view to move focus away from EditText.
3. When App is launched focus is on RelativeLayout, not on EditText(so that there is not blinking cursor in it.)
4. When a user clicks on Button I just move focus to RelativeLayout using requestFocus() call on RelativeLayout.
5. When user taps on EditText, keyboard comes up. I can enter text in that.

**What I want to achieve**

1. If I change orientation of phone when keyboard is visible then after orienation changes, keyboard should stay.
2. If keyboard is visible and some other activity comes on top of it for e.g. alarm, facebook chat heads, opening something from notification area, locking unlocking device, etc.. then on returning back to sample app keyboard should be visible.

**How I am achieving this**

1. In onSaveInstanceState(), I check if focus is on EditText then put a boolean variable in Bundle.
2. In onStop(), I am setting a one boolean flag `wasEditing = true`.
3. In onRestoreInstanceState(), I checked if Bundle has flag value set in onSaveInstanceState(). If yes then I am make `wasEditing = true`.
4. In onResume(), I check this `wasEditing` and if it is true, I request focus for EditText.
5. After that I call `imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT,resultRec)`

**Where I am getting problem**
Sometimes after executing this call, Keyboard is not visible in few cases, like during orientation change.
When I put logs I have found this function is returning `false`
But if I make this `showSoftInput()` call with some delay of 100ms using `mEditText.postDelayed()` in `onResume()` everything works fine.

**Question**
In what cases this function returns false and why delay is working?

**Note** 
Although I have solved my problem using delay, but I still want to know why it is behaving like that.

Comment: I am having this same exact issue, and it works when there is a delay, but not I call it in the onResume method without a delay.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I ran into today as well. Of my 8 android devices only 1 has the problem and it's running Android 4.0.4.

The problem was fixed by adding

```
mEditText.requestFocus();
mEditText.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

before calling 
    mEditText.showSoftInput(...)

You'll see the `resultcode` from `showSoftInput` is now `true`. I noticed that after the `mEditText.requestFocus()` the `isFocused()` was still `false`. Probably a bug in Android 4.0 and perhaps 4.1.

Comment: Adding requestFocusFromTouch() didn't solve my issue. I still get False from showSoftInput.

Answer (score 0):

Please call  showKeyboard after your mEditText is attached to window. 
Please make sure the time you make the call.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

I faced with this keyboard not showing up problem. I found the following solution inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43516620/6906562) but not their solution! In short the reason for this mess is that the request focus and the IMM provided service can only run on a view that is created and active. When you do all these on the creation phase `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance).. or  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater...` and the view is still in initializing state, you won't get an active view to act on! I have seen many solutions using delays and checks to wait for that view to get active then do the show keyboard but here is my solution based on the android frame work design:

**SOLUTION:**

in your activity or fragment override the following make sure your view has the access (define it in the top of the activity/fragment):

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    yourView.requestFocus();
    showSoftKeyboard(yourView);
    super.onStart();
}
 public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    if(view.requestFocus()){
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```