# Wait for Activity to resume before running a method

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have the following code I would like to execute in my onActivityResult() method:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(viewHolder.CertainEditTextView,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

This snippet should bring up the keyboard, allowing the user to type in to CertainEditTextView.

The issue: It does not work, and my theory is that this is because it runs before the Activity is fully loaded. I think this because if I run this code in a separate thread, after a delay of 1000ms, it works perfectly. This gives time the activity to load. This is not a real solution, and I am looking for a way to run this as soon as the Activity is done loading. onResume() would be a perfect method, but I only want to run this code snippet after onActivityResult is called.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onResume` *is* the perfect method I'd say since it is called after the `onActivityResult` call, you just need to set a flag such as a boolean to know if you're coming from the `onActivityResult` or another part of the lifecycle.

> Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.
>
> You will receive this call immediately **before onResume()** when your activity is re-starting.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

**UPDATE**

After the asker noted that this solution did **not** work for his specific need, You can consider using a `ViewTreeObserver` on the input to be notified when it's drawn and it should work. Something like this:

```
...
View yourView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.YOUD VIEW ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = yourView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
        //We are now sure the view is drawn and should be able to do what you wanted:
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(viewHolder.CertainEditTextView,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    } 
});
...
```

Comment: Juan, I agree with both you and Yazan that this would work. But I was thinking there would be a method that would allow me to prevent the use of state variables. Something that would allow me to add a runnable to the UI thread, and queue it at the end. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: UPDATE: Juan, actually, this solution does not work and I don't know why. I have to do a postDelayed of 50ms to get the keyboard to come up. This guy is having my exact same issue, and could only solve it using a post delayed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380123/why-android-inputmethodmanager-showsoftinput-returns-false

Comment: Postdelayed is only a cheap solution, try using a view tree observer on the field, and execute the code then http://stackoverflow.com/a/7735122/363262

Answer (score 0):

do something like this(Pseudo)

```
private boolean SHOW_KEYBOARD = false;

onCreate(...){

}
:
:

:
:

.... onActivityResult ()
    if(result == RESULT_OK && eqCode == myReqCode){
        SHOW_KEYBOARD = true;
    }
}

onResume(){
    if(SHOW_KEYBOARD ){
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(viewHolder.CertainEditTextView,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```