# How to force keyboard to show/hide?

Tags: android, keyboard

I tried to show keyboard after I inflate LinearLayout and call setContentView like:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(etContent, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
getContent.requestFocus();
```

It didn't work. I also tried this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

But it also didn't work. How can I force the keyboard to show/hide? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open

Answer (score 35):

This should work

```
public class KeyBoard {

    public static void toggle(Activity activity){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive()){
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); // hide
        } else {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY); // show
        }
    }//end method
}//end class
```

Comment: Nice answer still it worth :)

Comment: Saved my time... Its working...

Answer (score 1):

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) is clear about hiding the soft keyboard.
to show it you can use a hack - create an EditText anywhere in your layout, layout_width and layout_height=0dip, and in onCreate do

```
yourEditText.requestFocus();
```