# Show keyboard after pressing a button

Tags: android, button, keyboard, android-edittext

I have clear button to clear EditText.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bClearText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="clearEtSearch"
        android:background="@drawable/delete" />
```

This method clears EditText:

```
    public void clearEtSearch(View v) {
    etSearch.setText("");
    etSearch.requestFocus();
    showKeyboard(etSearch);
}
```

I have taken code below from hiding and changed to show keyboard, but it is not working

```
    private void showKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext()
            .getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (manager != null)
        manager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Please give suggestions to correct my code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but you can try to use `Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE` instead of just `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE`. Some are [Forcing the Soft Keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open) question for more.

You can also see [How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused) 
 See if following works:

```
public void clearEtSearch(View v) {
    etSearch.setText("");
    etSearch.requestFocus();

    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);    
    manager.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(etSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);

}
```

Depending on your need you may try different constants of [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) like following:

```
public void clearEtSearch(View v) {
    etSearch.setText("");
    etSearch.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);    
    manager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

or

```
public void clearEtSearch(View v) {
    etSearch.setText("");
    etSearch.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager manager= (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    manager.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
}
```

I haven't tried the code right not so not sure which one would work. See There are many related questions. Hope it works well for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this method and enjoy**

```
public void showSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```