# Soft keyboard doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm testing my app on android 4.0.4 Samsung galaxy duos, the problem is if I set:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

the keyboard doesn't appear, though it appears on the emulator. Any suggestions?

Here is how my `EditBox` looks like

```
<EditText 

        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapWords|textMultiLine"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        android:hint="@string/message"
        />
      <requestFocus />
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with textIsSelectable on devices

Comment: @HannahMitt try setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in the activity defined in the Manifest.xml that will keep the keyboard hidden(in my case it did)

Comment: I actually want the keyboard to show, not to be hidden. I just took out the textIsSelectable and then it behaved as normal. Didn't expect that behvaiour from that attribute.

Comment: adding `<requestFocus/>` doesn't help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a requestfocus.
In xml:

```
<EditText>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Programmatically

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

To "force" the SoftKeyboard to appear, you can do it dynamically:

```
InputMethodManager mImm = (InputMethodManager) 
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);  
mImm.showSoftInput(SearchEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Set onFocusChangeListener to appear your keyboard:

```
edittext.setFocusable(true);  
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {  
   @Override  
   public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {  
       if (hasFocus)   
           mImm.showSoftInput(SearchEdit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  
       else  
           mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);  
   } 
});
```

See [InputMethodManager Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) for more information.
**See also these answers to forcing the Keyboard to appear: [Forcing the Soft Keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open)**

Comment: it works if i show it on click event, im searching for a solution so i dont have to programatically pop it open, if i couldnt find one im gonna accept your answer... tnx

Comment: Do your focus work when `android:textIsSelectable` is true (I mean, is your cursor visible)? And if yes, your `Soft Keyboard` doesn't appear, right?

Comment: It's weird, but maybe you could do some things: like disabled `focus` in xml and add it dynamically / same with `textIsSelectable` / add a `onFocusChangeListener` to appear your keyboard (see my update answer)

Comment: Try this things one by one, etc. And let me know if it works, I'm curious about that weird issue. Thx

Comment: on a very tight schedule, i'll investigate it later and will give you feedback...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `requestFocus` inside `EditText` element:

```
<EditText 

        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textCapWords|textMultiLine"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:minLines="6"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:minHeight="140dp"
        android:hint="@string/message">
      <requestFocus />
<EditText/>
```

Comment: What happens if you try this on other devices?

Comment: i dont have another device ATM, if i show it programatically as suggested in the @Fllo answer it is shown

Comment: What else do you have in this layout? Isn't there another View that requests focus?

Comment: If you don't put `android:textIsSelectable="true"` then the focus behaves fine?

Comment: yup it behaves fine if i remove `textIsSelectable=true`

Comment: i removed the `<requestFocus/>` from the other box, it disabled by default so i also put ` android:focusable="false"` but to no effect

Comment: i have just checked that the copy/past option menu is not shown in the native sms application of the device, could that be interfering ?

Comment: Try to remove `android:focusable` property and make sure you have only this `EditText` with `requestFocus`. What happens then?

Comment: im gonna go with the manual approach... will investigate it later, tnx for your time...

Answer (score 0):

here is my extension fun

```
fun EditText.showKeyboardOnLayout() {
    val mEditText = this
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : 
      ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
          viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
          mEditText.apply {
            if (isShown && isFocusable && isEnabled && requestFocus()) {
            // The EditText is visible, focusable, enabled, and has received focus
            showKeyboardWithRetry()
        }
    }
}

  private fun showKeyboardWithRetry() {
      val inputMethodManager = 
        context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
     inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
     val isKeyboardShown = inputMethodManager.isActive(mEditText)
     if (!isKeyboardShown) {
        postDelayed({
            inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }, 100)
     }
    }
  })

}
```

Use like use like:
 `binding.phoneEditText.showKeyboardOnLayout()`