# Need to open alphanumeric google keyboard in Hybrid android application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, android-sdk-tools, ngcordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I need to open alphanumeric google keyboard in Hybrid android application. That particular keyboard is generally come for **password field** for any android devices. I need a solution for kiosk application. [Need to active this alphanumeric keyboard on my kiosk application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKnoG.jpg) .

Few details related query.

- Using android-19 Kitkat
- This the kiosk application specific devices not general android device.
- Hybrid application using **Apache Corodva**.
- Need to activate this particular keyboard for all **Address fields(text-field)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you have that keyboard installed and selected on device ? if yes,
   you can open it by one of these ways programmatically:
   [Forcing the Soft Keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479504/forcing-the-soft-keyboard-open)
2. If you want to select an installed keyboard programatically and your
   app has system privileges, use this solution to switch keyboards (
   activation ), Take a look on : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999658/2267723
3. Since your using Apache Corodva, you could ship a virtual keyboard
   (as html5 ) to app.  Take a look on
   https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/ to app and when user enters
   input, just call back your app with href with mimetype which is
   recognized by app.

**Other solutions:**

4. Create on-screen keyboard ( Im not talking about custom keyboard )
   its just layout as grid of buttons represents inputs.
5. Attach a physical Bt/USB keyboard.
6. Use a QR code . that would lead user to web where user can fill that form .. That would be free machine soon

Comment: Yes, Maher, I was able to solve this problem. I was using default keyboard **com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME** that's why it was not opening alphanumeric keypad, then I install **GBOARD** after that I was able to solve the issue. 

Do have any ideas that if we can open alphanumeric keypad using default alphanumeric keyboard provided by android? Because **GBOARD** is creating lots of unnecessary issues.

## **out of the track ** - Actully i was able to solve this issue after getting a mail from your side in my official email id  ;) B) i'am the same person.